# Manually clear or remove mediaelement.js players

Tags: backbone.js, mediaelement.js

I'm attempting to use the mediaelement.js player in a backbone.js site and I'm having trouble removing video/audio players manually when I move in and out of the various routes I have set up.

Let's say I have two videos on my page. When I move away from this page, these two videos are still preserved in memory:

```
> mejs.players
> [object, object]
```

When I return to the page, the original two videos are still in memory and an additional 2 videos are added to the players object:

```
> mejs.players
> [object, object, object, object]
```

In fact, every time I leave the page and then return, an additional 2 players are added to the `mejs.players` object.

Is there a way to clear/remove all of the players manually?

I've tried the following:

```
mejs.players[0].remove()
```

This seems to remove the player controls from the page, leaving the HTML5 video player. However, the player still persists when I check `mejs.players`. I could be wrong, but this doesn't seem optimal for performance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `mejs.players` to `[]`? (aka, resetting the array) When you call `mejs.players[0].remove()`, you're actually calling MediaElement's own `remove` function on the first player. I have no idea how that plugin works, so that might be why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm not too familiar with the best practices regarding memory management, but when I move between routes after emptying the array, it remains empty, which must mean something. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since this is for a Backbone site (which has UnderscoreJS), this would work, you can use _.keys() instead of Object.keys()

```
if (mejs) {
    var players = _.keys(mejs.players);
    _.each(players, function(player) {
        mejs.players[player].remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first delete  mejs.players and create new mejs.players array

if (mejs) {

delete mejs.players;

mejs.players = [];

}